# How to copy a <div> element from one page and paste it into another page using greasemonkey/tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Can you help me with my first greasemonkey script? I'm a complete beginner and would be ingenuously thankful for help. I've tried a lot, but always fail. *(edit: I've got some things working now)*

► In short, **I'd like to catch the [byline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byline) from an Austrian newspaper** *("Kurier")* **article and add it (slightly modified) to the article's print view.**

So here is what the [greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) script should do (*without external scripts such as jquery*):

- **step 1 (done)**: upon navigating to an article URL, redirect to the printview URL
- **step 2 (done)**: copy the byline from the article URL
- **step 3 (almost done)**: modify the byline (see below)
- **step 4**: paste the byline into the printview page

  comments for each step:

**[step 1]: done**
The print view of each article is located at `[article URL] + "/print"`,
for example:
      article URL: https://kurier.at/wissen/mars-simulation-auf-hawaii/249.106.702
print view URL: https://kurier.at/wissen/mars-simulation-auf-hawaii/249.106.702/print

This works for me:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        KURIER printview
// @include     https://kurier.at/*
// @exclude     https://kurier.at/*/print
// @version     1
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

window.location.replace(window.location + "/print");
```

I used `@exclude` to avoid an infinite loop.

To not slow down the script, it would be great if `@run-at document-start` could be left unchanged, so that the script does not have to render the article page but directly jumps to the printview URL. Hence only 1 page has to be rendered instead of 2 pages.

(My hope being that step 2 can either be accomplished from the printview location -- or else from the article page, but without rendering it? Either method would avoid rendering 2 pages.)

**[step 2]: done**
The byline is a div container, which comes in one of 3 different forms (depending on the number of authors):
• no author: `<div class="misc no-author">`
• single author: `<div class="misc single-author has-image">`
• multiple authors: `<div class="misc multiple-authors">`

Here are example articles for each type:
- no author: https://kurier.at/wissen/mars-experiment-auf-hawaii/218.311.221
- single author: https://kurier.at/wissen/mars-simulation-auf-hawaii/249.106.702
- multiple authors: https://kurier.at/wissen/mars-wann-ist-es-soweit/230.174.316

This gets us the div container:

```js
var $byline = document.getElementsByClassName("misc");
```

The byline is the first div.misc on the page, so the byline is now in `$byline[0]`.

**[step 3]**
The byline div container has this structure:

```html
<div class="misc [no-author/single-author/multiple-authors]">
    |__ [optional content]
    |__ <div class="last-modified">
    |__ <div class="social-media-container">
    |__ <div class="clear">
```

**a)** The social media container should be removed.
**b) (done)** The optional content may include an image.
The image URL scheme is: https://images.kurier.at/[imagename].jpg/[size]x[size]/[imageID]
If an image is present, the pixel values should be changed *from*:

```html
<img width="35" height="35" src="https://images.kurier.at/Sandra-
Lumetsberger(2)-REdit.jpg/70x70/133.396.913" alt="Sandra Lumetsberger">
```

*to:*

```html
<img width="100" height="100" src="https://images.kurier.at/Sandra-
Lumetsberger(2)-REdit.jpg/200x200/133.396.913" alt="Sandra Lumetsberger">
```

I only found this quick&dirty solution:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
    /height="35" width="35"/g,
    'height="100" width="100"').replace("/70x70/", "/200x200/");
```

**[step 4]**
The printview page has this structure:

```html
<body>
    |__ <script>
    |__ <div class="wrapper">
        |__ <header class="header">
        |__ <div class="rfloat noprint">
        |__ <p class="open12 marginb10">
        |__ <div class="clear">
        |__ <article>
```

The byline div copied in step 2 and modified in step 3 should be pasted below the p element.

Thank you so very much!

Comment: Good problem description *but*, this is more like a "code for me" request than a proper SO question. And it could easily be called "too broad".  The steps you need to take are (1) redirect, (2) AJAX-fetch the non-print version of the page and parse it for the author info, (3) wait for the current page to reach "document ready", (4) insert your info from step 2.

Comment: I'm sorry. Being a beginner, I thought it was a narrow question (copy/paste a div element) and quite easy for someone more knowledgeable than me. And thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

When changing to another URL, the script scope is released and a new script run is started on the next page. So you cannot transfer the data directly.

Have a look at [GM_getValue()](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue) & [GM_setValue()](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) functions.

You also need to include a [@grant](https://wiki.greasespot.net/@grant) in the header.

There are some other technics to exchange data between pages

- cookies
- HTML5 localStorage of modern browsers
- redirection into a GM controled Frame + messaging via custom events
- read another page via AJAX & integrate the manipulated data into the current page - GM supports a simplified [GM_xmlhttpRequest()](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) function.

I recommend the AJAX variant, but it depends on the behavior you intend to get.